# How to set category field for new item with Podio PHP API

Tags: php, podio

I have a Podio app which is populated by the php API via a form on a website.

Using the [Create Item](http://podio.github.io/podio-php/items/#create-item) snippet works for text fields, currency values, etc but have been I unable to untangle the documentation as to how to set a category field.

The category field, "attending", is a simple yes/no choice.

The method shown [here](http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/#category-field) generates a server error when combined with Create Item snippet as below:

```
$fields = new PodioItemFieldCollection(array(
      new PodioTextItemField(array("external_id" => "title", "values" => $name)),
      new PodioTextItemField(array("external_id" => "email", "values" => $email)),
));

$item = new PodioItem(array(
    'app' => new PodioApp(intval($app_id)),
    'fields' => $fields,
));

pseudo code: if attending = yes, $attending = 1, else $attending = 2 //id's of yes and no in category field

$item->fields['attending']->values = $attending;

$item->save();
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those still searching for an answer: **The trick is to use an array**.

Perform the evaluation of $attending before opening the Collection and then simply
add this line into the *PodioItemFieldCollection*.

```
new PodioCategoryItemField(array(
   'external_id' => 'attending', 'values' => array($attending))),
```

So the whole snippet would look like this

```
($foo == 'yes') ? $attending = 1: $attending = 2 ; // evaluating $foo for yes

$fields = new PodioItemFieldCollection(array(
  new PodioTextItemField(array("external_id" => "title", "values" => $name)),
  new PodioTextItemField(array("external_id" => "email", "values" => $email)),
  new PodioCategoryItemField(array(
    'external_id' => 'attending', 'values' => array($attending))) // must be an array
));

$item = new PodioItem(array(
'app' => new PodioApp(intval($app_id)),
'fields' => $fields,
));

$item->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find examples at: http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/#category-field

If it's still not working, place podio-php into debug mode so you can see what data is being sent to Podio: http://podio.github.io/podio-php/debug/

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but that's the page I mentioned in the question where I took the code snippet from. The code I have generates an Internal Server Error, so no Podio debug information is available.

Comment: While this answer may help to solve the OP's problem, it would be better to provide a full answer.